# MPU6050 Data Not Changing?

Tags: c, stm32, hal, mpu6050

I'm using an STM326050 MCU and I'm trying to get gyroscope and accelerometer data using an MPU6050([MPU6050 Registers](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf), [MPU6050 Datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf). I've made sure the MPU6050 is properly initialized and ready using the following code:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef initMPU6050(void) {
  uint8_t check;
  HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, MPU6050_WHO_AM_I_REG, 1, &check, 1, 1000);
  if (check == 0x68) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, LD2_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(200);
    }
    // the regSet variables set the gyro and accel to 500deg/s and 4g respectively
    uint8_t gyroRegSet = 0x08;
    uint8_t accelRegSet = 0x08;
    uint8_t pwrMgmtSet = 0;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;
    ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, MPU6050_GYRO_REG, 1, &gyroRegSet, 1, 100);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) {return HAL_ERROR;}
    HAL_Delay(50);
    ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, MPU6050_ACCEL_REG, 1, &accelRegSet, 1, 100);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) {return HAL_ERROR;}
    HAL_Delay(50);
    ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, MPU6050_PWE_MGMT_REG, 1, &pwrMgmtSet, 1, 100);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) {return HAL_ERROR;}
    return HAL_OK;
  }
  return HAL_ERROR;
```

Afterwords, I tried to gather Gyroscope data in the X direction (making sure one axis works before expanding to all 6-axises) using the following code:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef readGyroGx(uint16_t* Gx, HAL_StatusTypeDef init) {
  if (init != HAL_OK) {return HAL_ERROR;}
  uint8_t gxh;`
  uint8_t gxl;
  HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, 0x43, 1, &gxh, 1, 1000);
  HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, 0x44, 1, &gxl, 1, 1000);
  Gx = (gxh<<8) | gxl;
}
```

And displaying it to a screen using:

```
uint16_t buf[20];
  HAL_StatusTypeDef init = initMPU6050();
  uint16_t gx;
  while (1)
  {
    readGyroGx(&gx, init);
    sprintf((char*)buf, "%u \r\n", gx);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf), 1000);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, LD2_Pin);
    HAL_Delay(100);
  }
```

I've tried rotating and moving the MPU6050 around but no matter how I moved it the Gx value seems to be stuck at the value 60254. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, turns out with my `Gx = (gxh<<8) | gxl;` line I needed to use *Gx not Gx. And for outputting data, I was supposed to use `%hu` no %u.

Comment: `Gx = (gxh<<8) | gxl;` shouldn't compile. Assuming this is gcc, make sure that you have all warnings enabled and that C standard violations are reported as errors. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)